# Implementing C# Dictionary results in error: Does not have matching return type

Tags: c#, inheritance, dictionary, struct

I am trying to understand how C# implements the [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx). It seems to me that Dictionary is supposed to inherit from IEnumerable which requires the method implementation for:

```
IEnumerable GetEnumerator()
```

However, the C# Dictionary instead implements:

```
Dictionary<T>.Enumerator GetEnumerator()
```

Where [Enumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c6ftx8b.aspx) is a nested struct which inherits from IEnumerator.

I have created an example of this relationship:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    IFoo GetFoo();
}

public abstract class Foo : IFoo
{
    public abstract FooInternal GetFoo();

    public struct FooInternal : IFoo
    {
        public IFoo GetFoo()
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't compile, resulting in the following error:

```
Error   2   'Foo' does not implement interface member 'IFoo.GetFoo()'. 'Foo.GetFoo()' cannot implement 'IFoo.GetFoo()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'CodeGenerator.UnitTests.IFoo'. Foo.cs  14
```

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong here? How does C# implement the Dictionary? How would one make the example code compile similarly to the C# Dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing two distinct interfaces, namely **`IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator`**.

The outer class, the dictionary class, implements `IEnumerable`. This involves that the outer class has a method `GetEnumerator`. This method returns an instance of the nested (inner) struct.

The inner struct implements `IEnumerator`. To implement `IEnumerator` you must have a `MoveNext` method and a `Current` property.

Besides, there's the issue of explicit interface implementation which is mentioned also by Andrey Shchekin's answer. This code is legal and similar to `Dictionary<,>`:

```
public interface IFoo   // corresponds to IEnumerable
{
  IBar GetBar();
}

public interface IBar   // corresponds to IEnumerator
{
}


public class Foo : IFoo
{
  // public method that has BarInternal as return type
  public BarInternal GetBar()
  {
    return new BarInternal();
  }

  // explicit interface implementation which calls the public method above
  IBar IFoo.GetBar()
  {
    return GetBar();
  }

  public struct BarInternal : IBar
  {
  }
}
```

It would also be possible to implement the `IFoo` "directly" (not explicitly) by a public method, but then the declared return type must match:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
  // public method that directly implements the interface
  public IBar GetBar()
  {
    return new BarInternal();
  }

  public struct BarInternal : IBar
  {
  }
}
```

The reason why `Dictionary<,>` isn't written in this simpler way, is that you get boxing of the nested struct, I guess.

Note that when you `foreach` through a `Dictionary<,>`, the C# compiler first searches for a public non-generic parameterless instance method with the exact name `GetEnumerator`. If such a method is found, it is used, and the compiler doesn't care about `IEnumerable`. Therefore, with a `Dictionary<,>`, the slightly more optimal public method which does **not** implement the interface, is used during `foreach`.

Explicit interface implementations are documented on MSDN. See [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.GetEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc673105.aspx) (generic) and [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348449.aspx) (non-generic).

Comment: Thanks for the extended explanation!  Really helpful.  Any idea how to check, using reflection, if a Type's method is an explicit method?

Comment: There might be better ways, but as a rule of thumb, if `methodInfo.Name.Contains(".")` then it would be an explicit interface implementation. Or maybe that's not what you ask?

Comment: Well, an explicit method is a private method.  Solution I found is to use InterfaceMapping to get the explicit methods.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing an explicit interface implementation:

```
public abstract class Foo : IFoo
{
    public abstract FooInternal GetFoo();

    // start here
    IFoo IFoo.GetFoo()
    {
        return GetFoo();
    }
    // end here

    public struct FooInternal : IFoo
    {
        public IFoo GetFoo()
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```